# creating a matrix of flags for given dates in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create zeros in my dataframe for particular date ranges for selective columns. I am stuck at finding any efficient solution.

My code creates a matrix of 1s. lets say dates=1/10/2016 - 16/8/2018 (i.e.ytd). `matrix1cols=A,B,C,D:`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(shape=(len(dates), len(matrix1cols))), index=dates)
df.columns = ['A','B','C', 'D']
```

Now, I wish to make the Q1 (jan-mar) dates for column A = 0, Q2 dates for B = 0, Q3 dates for C = 0 and Q4 dates for col D = 0, for all years, in df. (I am essentially creating flags for myself)

Ps- my date has many years, and I have simplified the dataset for purpose of ease.

Comment: What elegance. May I apologise; my question wasn't specific enough. I figured I would be able to work with what came back.... as it happens, what I actually need is: I need 0's in Q3 and Q4 for A, 0's in Q2 and Q3 in B, 0's in Q1 and Q2 in C, and 0's in Q2 and Q3 for D. Again, being new, im sorry my Q wasn't precise enough. (And thanks to piRsquared for providing a setup)

Comment: You should [edit] the question with the updated information.  And are you sure you want `Q2` and `Q3` for column `D'?  That seems inconsistent with what you have for the other columns.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Its a little inconsistent, and being fairly new to python, was driving me in circles. Thank you. I will try to edit the question just now, I appreciate the (v speedy) help.

Comment: So zeros in the same places for both B and D?

Comment: No, for B, zeros in Q2 and Q3. For D, zeros in Q2 and Q4. (you were absolutely right); just trying to figure out how to edit the question

Comment: See my update.  I define the mapping via an array.  Make sure that array is consistent with what you were thinking/need.

Comment: legend. Thanks ever so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Setup

```
dates = pd.date_range('2016/10/01', '2018/08/16', freq='M')
matrixcols = list('ABCD')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((len(dates), len(matrixcols)), int), dates, matrixcols)

            A  B  C  D
2016-10-31  1  1  1  1
2016-11-30  1  1  1  1
2016-12-31  1  1  1  1
2017-01-31  1  1  1  1
2017-02-28  1  1  1  1
2017-03-31  1  1  1  1
2017-04-30  1  1  1  1
2017-05-31  1  1  1  1
2017-06-30  1  1  1  1
2017-07-31  1  1  1  1
2017-08-31  1  1  1  1
2017-09-30  1  1  1  1
2017-10-31  1  1  1  1
2017-11-30  1  1  1  1
2017-12-31  1  1  1  1
2018-01-31  1  1  1  1
2018-02-28  1  1  1  1
2018-03-31  1  1  1  1
2018-04-30  1  1  1  1
2018-05-31  1  1  1  1
2018-06-30  1  1  1  1
2018-07-31  1  1  1  1
```

---

### Numpy slicing

Create a custom array that defines where to place zeros

```
i = np.array([
    #A  B  C  D
    [1, 1, 0, 1],  # Q1 -> Only column C is zero
    [1, 0, 0, 0],  # Q2 -> cols B, C, D are zero
    [0, 0, 1, 1],  # Q3 -> cols A, B are zero
    [0, 1, 1, 0],  # Q4 -> cols A, D are zero
])

q = df.index.quarter - 1
df * i[q]

            A  B  C  D
2016-10-31  0  1  1  0
2016-11-30  0  1  1  0
2016-12-31  0  1  1  0
2017-01-31  1  1  0  1
2017-02-28  1  1  0  1
2017-03-31  1  1  0  1
2017-04-30  1  0  0  0
2017-05-31  1  0  0  0
2017-06-30  1  0  0  0
2017-07-31  0  0  1  1
2017-08-31  0  0  1  1
2017-09-30  0  0  1  1
2017-10-31  0  1  1  0
2017-11-30  0  1  1  0
2017-12-31  0  1  1  0
2018-01-31  1  1  0  1
2018-02-28  1  1  0  1
2018-03-31  1  1  0  1
2018-04-30  1  0  0  0
2018-05-31  1  0  0  0
2018-06-30  1  0  0  0
2018-07-31  0  0  1  1
```

---

Another view to see that it is working for correct quarters.

```
i = np.array([
    #A  B  C  D
    [1, 1, 0, 1],  # Q1 -> Only column C is zero
    [1, 0, 0, 0],  # Q2 -> cols B, C, D are zero
    [0, 0, 1, 1],  # Q3 -> cols A, B are zero
    [0, 1, 1, 0],  # Q4 -> cols A, D are zero
])

q = df.index.quarter - 1
df.set_index(df.index.to_period('Q'), append=True).swaplevel(0, 1) * i[q]

                   A  B  C  D
2016Q4 2016-10-31  0  1  1  0
       2016-11-30  0  1  1  0
       2016-12-31  0  1  1  0
2017Q1 2017-01-31  1  1  0  1
       2017-02-28  1  1  0  1
       2017-03-31  1  1  0  1
2017Q2 2017-04-30  1  0  0  0
       2017-05-31  1  0  0  0
       2017-06-30  1  0  0  0
2017Q3 2017-07-31  0  0  1  1
       2017-08-31  0  0  1  1
       2017-09-30  0  0  1  1
2017Q4 2017-10-31  0  1  1  0
       2017-11-30  0  1  1  0
       2017-12-31  0  1  1  0
2018Q1 2018-01-31  1  1  0  1
       2018-02-28  1  1  0  1
       2018-03-31  1  1  0  1
2018Q2 2018-04-30  1  0  0  0
       2018-05-31  1  0  0  0
       2018-06-30  1  0  0  0
2018Q3 2018-07-31  0  0  1  1
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use a simple `for` loop. Take care to convert your index to `datetime` as a preliminary step, e.g. via `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`.

```
for q, col in enumerate(df, 1):
    df.loc[df.index.quarter == q, col] = 0
```

Equivalently, in this case, but more verbose:

```
for q, col in zip(range(1, 5), df):
    df.loc[df.index.quarter == q, col] = 0
```